# Error - Tag Insert : no value defined for bean

Tags: struts-1

i'm new to struts. i will use struts tile in my Java EE project. 
i read following page that illustrate how to use tile.
[struts tiles examples](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-tiles/examples.html)

i read the page and try do all thing that mentained in the page. in the below you can my files detail.

struts-config.xml:

```
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
</plug-in>
```

tiles-defs.xml:

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="role.list" path="/WEB-INF/content/layout.jsp">
    <put name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/admin/restricted/role_list_body.jsp"
        type="page" />
</definition>
```

role_list_body.jsp:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      List of Roles
   </body>
</html>
```

and role_list.jsp is:

```
<body>
   <sTile:insert beanName="role.list"/>
</body>
```

i think all of things is correct. but when i call role_list.jsp i get following error:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:  javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error - Tag Insert : No value defined for bean 'role.list' with property 'null' in scope 'null'.
          org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:442)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error - Tag Insert : No value defined for bean 'role.list' with property 'null' in scope 'null'.
     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.content.admin.restericted.role.role_005flist_jsp._jspService(role_005flist_jsp.java:80)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error - Tag Insert : No value defined for bean 'role.list' with property 'null' in scope 'null'.
org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.processBean(InsertTag.java:667)
org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.createTagHandler(InsertTag.java:483)
org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doStartTag(InsertTag.java:441)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.content.admin.restericted.role.role_005flist_jsp._jspx_meth_sTile_005finsert_005f0(role_005flist_jsp.java:97)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.content.admin.restericted.role.role_005flist_jsp._jspService(role_005flist_jsp.java:70)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.
```

do you know what this problem occourred.
thanks.

Comment: in role_list.jsp file i replace `<sTile:insert beanName="role.list"` /> to `<sTile:insert name="role.list"` /> . now error changed.  new exception is :  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/content/admin/restericted/role/role_list.jsp at line 12

9: <title>Insert title here</title>
10: </head>
11: <body>
12:  <sTile:insert name="role.list"/>
13: </body>
14: </html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find problem.
in the role_list.jsp i replace
`<sTile:insert beanName="role.list" />` with `<sTile:insert definition="role.list" />`

now  it works true.